# How do I list all entity types from the db object?

Tags: python, ponyorm

I am using the latest ponyorm on Python 3.6.

I want to do some monkey patching on entity classes created at another stage (to add computed fields).

Any chance I can get the list of entities types available from the db object ?

In my models.py file:

```
from pony.orm import *
db = Database()

class OneEntity(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    nom = Required(str)

class AnotherEntity(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    someprop = Required(str)
```

In another file:

```
from models import *
db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename = 'test.db', create_db = True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables = True)

def say_hello():
    """ some dummy proc to monkey patch onto entity classes"""
    print("hello")

#This works, but isn't workable for my use case (too many entity classes)
OneEntity.monkey_patched_method = say_hello


#And here I'd like to have the ability to list entity classes programmatically

for Entity in some_code_that_i_dont_know :
    Entity.new_method = say_hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PonyORM `Database` object has `entities` property which is a dict of all associated entities:

```py
for entity_name, entity_cls in db.entities.items():
    print(entity_name)
```

Comment: validating this answer because it is more what I was thinking, but frankly both other (looking for generic subclass thru python itself) are fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to obtain subclasses of `Entity` using the `__subclasses__` method.

This example is from Flask SQLAlchemy. Your results should be similar:

```
>>> db.Model.__subclasses__()                                                                                                                               
[myapp.models.User,
 myapp.models.Organization,
 myapp.models.Customer,
 myapp.models.Address,
 ...
]
```

In your code, you should do the following:

```
for Entity in db.Entity.__subclasses__():
    Entity.new_method = say_hello
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider upvoting it or accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t specific to Pony, but, you can use [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) to do this:

```py
import inspect
import models


for name, attr in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(attr) and issubclass(attr, db.Entity:
        models.__dict__[name].new_method = say_hello
```

Basically this will run through all the attributes of the `models` module and add `new_method` to any `db.Entity` subclasses it encounters.